# Using the Item Template To Bind Values From 3 Dropdowns Into A Single Value

Tags: asp.net

I am using an asp.net details view. I added an entry into the details view like so...

```
 <asp:BoundField DataField="DTMON_F" HeaderText="Monday Start:" InsertVisible="False"
            ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="DTMON_F" Visible="false" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="*Monday Start: " SortExpression="DTMON_F">
            <EditItemTemplate>
               <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMondayStartHour" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="6">6am</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="7">7am</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="8">8am</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="9">9am</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
                &nbsp;:
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMondayStartMin" runat="server"> 
                    <asp:ListItem Value="00">00</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="15">15</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="30">30</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="45">45</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
                   &nbsp;:
                   <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMonAMPM" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="AM">AM</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="PM">PM</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblMonday" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DTMON_F") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Now I need to FIRST concatinate the values from the dropdown then bind the data gathered in the edit template form the 3 dropdowns. How might I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the updated event of the detailsview which is called after you changed your values. The you can concatinate your values by code.

```
 void CustomerDetail_ItemUpdated(object sender, 
    DetailsViewUpdatedEventArgs e)
  {
    // set your label value consisting of 3 dropdown values
    CustomersView.DataBind();
  }
```

Comment: sorry if im wrong, but i think the event should be itemupdating

Comment: well it depends if you want to call the code before or after the updating event: itemupdating would be before the actual updating process - itemupdated whoudl be afterwards